Dynamic Astro.js Link with data from api
We have a page where we are going to call some data from API, and use one of these data to create a variable link.
Our page code includes the following which calls 3 variables from API. I plan to use {data.postal} to create variable links, for example:
my URL website is: Serino.ir
and i want to create serino.ir/?land={data.postal}
I wrote the code of the page where it shows the data (Main.jsx), but I have a problem to write the .astro template code and I don't know how to write it.
Main.jsx:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Function to fetch data from the API
const fetchDataFromAPI = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/161.185.160.93/geo");

  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data from API");
  }
};

export const MarketerInfo = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const apiData = await fetchDataFromAPI();
        setData(apiData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <section className="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-24">
      <div className="p-6 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow-md text-center">
        <h1 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4 text-gray-800">
          Marketer: {data.city}
        </h1>
        <p className="mb-4">Postal Code: {data.postal}</p>
        <a
          href={data.readme}
          className="inline-block bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-green-600 transition-colors duration-300"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Visit Your Dynamic Page
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default MarketerInfo;

anyone can help to complete .astro file?
---
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar.jsx";
import {MarketerInfo} from "../components/Marketer/Main.jsx"; // Corrected import statement
import "../styles/Theme.css";
import "../styles/Diagonals.css";
import "../assets/font/fontiran.css";


---

<Layout title="Serino">
  <Navbar client:load />
  <MarketerInfo client:load />
</Layout>

regards.

what's the problem? what have you tried and how exacgtl did it not work?

the problem is i want o create dynamic route according to {data.postal}:
serino.ir/?marketer={data.postal}

what's the problem with <a href={'https://serino.ir/?marketer=' + data.postal}> ? Perhaps you're looking to encode the data with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams ? but it's hard to help you if you don't even post example data.
